# How can I redirect from within a Marionette Controller to another route?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

How can I redirect from within a Marionette Controller to another route? For example:

```
var controller = new MyAccountController({
    myAccountView: new MyAccountView({
        el: 'body'
    })
});

var router = new MyAccountRouter({
    controller: controller
});
```

From within a controller method, I don't have access to the router to my knowledge and I think you need to access the navigate() method from the router in order to navigate. Basically what I want to do is client-side redirect somewhere if certain conditions in a controller method aren't met.

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred way would be to trigger an event that another object could listen for. Here's a small example of the kind of thing I would do (untested).

```
window.App = new Marionette.Application();
App.on('start', function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
App.start();

var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        '': 'home'
    }
});

var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    home: function() {
        App.trigger('someEvent');
    }
});

var AnotherController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    doSomeOtherThing: function() {
        alert('Hello world');
    });

    App.on('someEvent', function() {
        doSomeOtherThing();
    });
});

var controller = new Controller;
var anotherController = new AnotherController;
controller.router = new Router({
    controller: controller
});
controller.start();
anotherController.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Backbone history object for this purpose:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/some/route', {
    trigger: true
});
```

The above would update the URL to `/some/route` and force the router to trigger the route handler.